Trying to duplicate a pdf file hangs on write using TCPDI
I'm trying to sign a PDF file with a certificate and I have some fallbacks for when it fails, like reading the PDF file and writing a new file then signing that file, reading the PDF file as image, add thos images to a new pdf and sign that, etc...
I'm having trouble with one particualr case
function duplicar_pdf($filepath)
{
    require_once TCPDF_PATH . 'tcpdf.php';
    require_once TCPDF_PATH . 'tcpdi.php';

    $outputDir = DOL_DATA_ROOT . '/' . dirname($filepath) . '/';

    try {
        // Create new PDF document
        $pdf = new TCPDI();

        // Set the source file
        $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile(DOL_DATA_ROOT . '/' . $filepath);

        // Iterate through each page
        for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
            // Import a page
            $templateId = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);

            // Get the size of the imported page
            $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($templateId);

            // Create a new page in the PDF with the same size as the original page
            $pdf->AddPage($size['width'] > $size['height'] ? 'L' : 'P', [$size['width'], $size['height']]);

            // Use the imported page as a template
            $pdf->useTemplate($templateId);
        }

        // Output the new PDF
        $newPdfFile = $outputDir . pathinfo($filepath, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . '_copia.pdf';
        $pdf->Output($newPdfFile, 'F');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        dol_syslog(var_export('Error: ' . $e->getMessage(), true));
        return false;
    }

    return $newPdfFile;
}

When reaching $pdf->Output($newPdfFile, 'F'); I get this output

Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utlr' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706

Call Stack:
    0.0004     403224   1. {main}() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/documents/fournisseur/facture/1/7/EV-FP24-01435/run.php:0
    0.0004     403288   2. duplicar_pdf($filepath = '/share/Web/dolibarr/documents/fournisseur/facture/1/7/EV-FP24-01435/EV-FP24-01435-invoice1.pdf') /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/documents/fournisseur/facture/1/7/EV-FP24-01435/run.php:68
    0.0561    9150792   3. TCPDF->Output($name = '/share/Web/dolibarr/documents/fournisseur/facture/1/7/EV-FP24-01435/EV-FP24-01435-invoice1_copia.pdf', $dest = 'F') /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/documents/fournisseur/facture/1/7/EV-FP24-01435/run.php:51
    0.0562    9150792   4. TCPDF->Close() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php:7927
    0.0570    9158360   5. TCPDI->_enddoc() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php:3050
    0.0570    9158360   6. TCPDF->_enddoc() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi.php:575
    0.0578    9175704   7. TCPDF->_putresources() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php:10307
    0.0578    9176336   8. FPDF_TPL->_putimages() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php:9793
    0.0578    9176336   9. TCPDI->_putformxobjects() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/fpdf_tpl.php:437
    0.0582    9188920  10. TCPDI->_putimportedobjects() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi.php:393
    0.0582    9189296  11. tcpdi_parser->getObjectVal($obj = [0 => 8, 1 => 7, 2 => 0]) /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi.php:259
    0.0583    9190080  12. tcpdi_parser->getIndirectObject($obj_ref = '7_0', $offset = 539638, $decoding = FALSE) /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php:999
    0.0583    9190520  13. tcpdi_parser->getRawObject($offset = 539645, $data = ???) /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php:960
    0.0583    9190520  14. tcpdi_parser->getDictValue($offset = 539647, $data = '%PDF-1.3\r\n%����\r\n%RSTXPDF3 Parameters:\r\n2 0 obj\r\n<<\r\n/Filter 3 0 R\r\n/Length 4 0 R\r\n/Length1 1036584\r\n>>\r\nstream\r\nx��\a�%E�?~��\034ox�M�1�0y`�\031\026�Q\034\020q\b\002�C\020D\021\0312\b\n��Q$\030pU�E@\004\004D@1`Bwa\021AP1�\021E�\twu\025#0���������7o\006v�>��o�;U����+�:�N�����D�˻w]��n�|{���\030�Qd�\033w���k���\035R,?F�{�n�>���/K�\017_�����\036��\'�z�礵�7E����k�_s��cCi}�\032�:{����~�\027\016�Od��t.~��e+F�|�[\005\017��K�}�^�?�����^��\035\016�u�\027�����(r�����#N<���_��\006iv�\027Y�#^}�\026\037�����\vv\024\t_~��G����-��3\016\025�>~�᧜,3�i(�\004��>���\034uY��K���\\�m\017=f݉����+~"r�/���9����=�\003�.Ҹ��?\006\027���:\f稯�=��SO;��'...) /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php:793
    0.0585    9191832  15. tcpdi_parser->getRawObject($offset = 'Type', $data = '\r\n%Devtype SAPWIN   Font ZARIAL1  normal Lang ES\r\n/Type /Font\r\n/Subtype /TrueType\r\n/BaseFont /Arial\r\n/Name /F001\r\n/Encoding 6 0 R\r\n/FirstChar 32\r\n/LastChar 255\r\n%Charwidth values from SAPWIN ZARIAL1 120 normal\r\n/Widths\r\n[ 275 275 354 554 554 888 667 192 333 333 388 583 275 333 275 275 554 554 554 554 554 554 554 554 554 554 275 275 583 583 583 554 1017 667 667 721 721 667 608 775 721 275 500 667 554 833 721 775 667 775 721 667 608 721 667 942 667 667 608 275 275 275 471\r\n 554 333 554 554 500 554 554 275 554'...) /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php:911


Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utls' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706

Call Stack:
    0.0004     403224   1. {main}() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/documents/fournisseur/facture/1/7/EV-FP24-01435/run.php:0
    0.0004     403288   2. duplicar_pdf($filepath = '/share/Web/dolibarr/documents/fournisseur/facture/1/7/EV-FP24-01435/EV-FP24-01435-invoice1.pdf') /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/documents/fournisseur/facture/1/7/EV-FP24-01435/run.php:68
    0.0561    9150792   3. TCPDF->Output($name = '/share/Web/dolibarr/documents/fournisseur/facture/1/7/EV-FP24-01435/EV-FP24-01435-invoice1_copia.pdf', $dest = 'F') /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/documents/fournisseur/facture/1/7/EV-FP24-01435/run.php:51
    0.0562    9150792   4. TCPDF->Close() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php:7927
    0.0570    9158360   5. TCPDI->_enddoc() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php:3050
    0.0570    9158360   6. TCPDF->_enddoc() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi.php:575
    0.0578    9175704   7. TCPDF->_putresources() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php:10307
    0.0578    9176336   8. FPDF_TPL->_putimages() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php:9793
    0.0578    9176336   9. TCPDI->_putformxobjects() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/fpdf_tpl.php:437
    0.0582    9188920  10. TCPDI->_putimportedobjects() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi.php:393
    0.0582    9189296  11. tcpdi_parser->getObjectVal($obj = [0 => 8, 1 => 7, 2 => 0]) /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi.php:259
    0.0583    9190080  12. tcpdi_parser->getIndirectObject($obj_ref = '7_0', $offset = 539638, $decoding = FALSE) /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php:999
    0.0583    9190520  13. tcpdi_parser->getRawObject($offset = 539645, $data = ???) /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php:960
    0.0583    9190520  14. tcpdi_parser->getDictValue($offset = 539647, $data = '%PDF-1.3\r\n%����\r\n%RSTXPDF3 Parameters:\r\n2 0 obj\r\n<<\r\n/Filter 3 0 R\r\n/Length 4 0 R\r\n/Length1 1036584\r\n>>\r\nstream\r\nx��\a�%E�?~��\034ox�M�1�0y`�\031\026�Q\034\020q\b\002�C\020D\021\0312\b\n��Q$\030pU�E@\004\004D@1`Bwa\021AP1�\021E�\twu\025#0���������7o\006v�>��o�;U����+�:�N�����D�˻w]��n�|{���\030�Qd�\033w���k���\035R,?F�{�n�>���/K�\017_�����\036��\'�z�礵�7E����k�_s��cCi}�\032�:{����~�\027\016�Od��t.~��e+F�|�[\005\017��K�}�^�?�����^��\035\016�u�\027�����(r�����#N<���_��\006iv�\027Y�#^}�\026\037�����\vv\024\t_~��G����-��3\016\025�>~�᧜,3�i(�\004��>���\034uY��K���\\�m\017=f݉����+~"r�/���9����=�\003�.Ҹ��?\006\027���:\f稯�=��SO;��'...) /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php:793
    0.0585    9191832  15. tcpdi_parser->getRawObject($offset = 'Type', $data = '\r\n%Devtype SAPWIN   Font ZARIAL1  normal Lang ES\r\n/Type /Font\r\n/Subtype /TrueType\r\n/BaseFont /Arial\r\n/Name /F001\r\n/Encoding 6 0 R\r\n/FirstChar 32\r\n/LastChar 255\r\n%Charwidth values from SAPWIN ZARIAL1 120 normal\r\n/Widths\r\n[ 275 275 354 554 554 888 667 192 333 333 388 583 275 333 275 275 554 554 554 554 554 554 554 554 554 554 275 275 583 583 583 554 1017 667 667 721 721 667 608 775 721 275 500 667 554 833 721 775 667 775 721 667 608 721 667 942 667 667 608 275 275 275 471\r\n 554 333 554 554 500 554 554 275 554'...) /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php:911


Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utlt' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706

Call Stack:
    0.0004     403224   1. {main}() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/documents/fournisseur/facture/1/7/EV-FP24-01435/run.php:0
    0.0004     403288   2. duplicar_pdf($filepath = '/share/Web/dolibarr/documents/fournisseur/facture/1/7/EV-FP24-01435/EV-FP24-01435-invoice1.pdf') /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/documents/fournisseur/facture/1/7/EV-FP24-01435/run.php:68
    0.0561    9150792   3. TCPDF->Output($name = '/share/Web/dolibarr/documents/fournisseur/facture/1/7/EV-FP24-01435/EV-FP24-01435-invoice1_copia.pdf', $dest = 'F') /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/documents/fournisseur/facture/1/7/EV-FP24-01435/run.php:51
    0.0562    9150792   4. TCPDF->Close() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php:7927
    0.0570    9158360   5. TCPDI->_enddoc() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php:3050
    0.0570    9158360   6. TCPDF->_enddoc() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi.php:575
    0.0578    9175704   7. TCPDF->_putresources() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php:10307
    0.0578    9176336   8. FPDF_TPL->_putimages() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php:9793
    0.0578    9176336   9. TCPDI->_putformxobjects() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/fpdf_tpl.php:437
    0.0582    9188920  10. TCPDI->_putimportedobjects() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi.php:393
    0.0582    9189296  11. tcpdi_parser->getObjectVal($obj = [0 => 8, 1 => 7, 2 => 0]) /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi.php:259
    0.0583    9190080  12. tcpdi_parser->getIndirectObject($obj_ref = '7_0', $offset = 539638, $decoding = FALSE) /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php:999
    0.0583    9190520  13. tcpdi_parser->getRawObject($offset = 539645, $data = ???) /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php:960
    0.0583    9190520  14. tcpdi_parser->getDictValue($offset = 539647, $data = '%PDF-1.3\r\n%����\r\n%RSTXPDF3 Parameters:\r\n2 0 obj\r\n<<\r\n/Filter 3 0 R\r\n/Length 4 0 R\r\n/Length1 1036584\r\n>>\r\nstream\r\nx��\a�%E�?~��\034ox�M�1�0y`�\031\026�Q\034\020q\b\002�C\020D\021\0312\b\n��Q$\030pU�E@\004\004D@1`Bwa\021AP1�\021E�\twu\025#0���������7o\006v�>��o�;U����+�:�N�����D�˻w]��n�|{���\030�Qd�\033w���k���\035R,?F�{�n�>���/K�\017_�����\036��\'�z�礵�7E����k�_s��cCi}�\032�:{����~�\027\016�Od��t.~��e+F�|�[\005\017��K�}�^�?�����^��\035\016�u�\027�����(r�����#N<���_��\006iv�\027Y�#^}�\026\037�����\vv\024\t_~��G����-��3\016\025�>~�᧜,3�i(�\004��>���\034uY��K���\\�m\017=f݉����+~"r�/���9����=�\003�.Ҹ��?\006\027���:\f稯�=��SO;��'...) /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php:793
    0.0585    9191832  15. tcpdi_parser->getRawObject($offset = 'Type', $data = '\r\n%Devtype SAPWIN   Font ZARIAL1  normal Lang ES\r\n/Type /Font\r\n/Subtype /TrueType\r\n/BaseFont /Arial\r\n/Name /F001\r\n/Encoding 6 0 R\r\n/FirstChar 32\r\n/LastChar 255\r\n%Charwidth values from SAPWIN ZARIAL1 120 normal\r\n/Widths\r\n[ 275 275 354 554 554 888 667 192 333 333 388 583 275 333 275 275 554 554 554 554 554 554 554 554 554 554 275 275 583 583 583 554 1017 667 667 721 721 667 608 775 721 275 500 667 554 833 721 775 667 775 721 667 608 721 667 942 667 667 608 275 275 275 471\r\n 554 333 554 554 500 554 554 275 554'...) /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php:911


Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utlu' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706

Call Stack:
    0.0004     403224   1. {main}() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/documents/fournisseur/facture/1/7/EV-FP24-01435/run.php:0
    0.0004     403288   2. duplicar_pdf($filepath = '/share/Web/dolibarr/documents/fournisseur/facture/1/7/EV-FP24-01435/EV-FP24-01435-invoice1.pdf') /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/documents/fournisseur/facture/1/7/EV-FP24-01435/run.php:68
    0.0561    9150792   3. TCPDF->Output($name = '/share/Web/dolibarr/documents/fournisseur/facture/1/7/EV-FP24-01435/EV-FP24-01435-invoice1_copia.pdf', $dest = 'F') /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/documents/fournisseur/facture/1/7/EV-FP24-01435/run.php:51
    0.0562    9150792   4. TCPDF->Close() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php:7927
    0.0570    9158360   5. TCPDI->_enddoc() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php:3050
    0.0570    9158360   6. TCPDF->_enddoc() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi.php:575
    0.0578    9175704   7. TCPDF->_putresources() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php:10307
    0.0578    9176336   8. FPDF_TPL->_putimages() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tecnickcom/tcpdf/tcpdf.php:9793
    0.0578    9176336   9. TCPDI->_putformxobjects() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/fpdf_tpl.php:437
    0.0582    9188920  10. TCPDI->_putimportedobjects() /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi.php:393
    0.0582    9189296  11. tcpdi_parser->getObjectVal($obj = [0 => 8, 1 => 7, 2 => 0]) /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi.php:259
    0.0583    9190080  12. tcpdi_parser->getIndirectObject($obj_ref = '7_0', $offset = 539638, $decoding = FALSE) /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php:999
    0.0583    9190520  13. tcpdi_parser->getRawObject($offset = 539645, $data = ???) /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php:960
    0.0583    9190520  14. tcpdi_parser->getDictValue($offset = 539647, $data = '%PDF-1.3\r\n%����\r\n%RSTXPDF3 Parameters:\r\n2 0 obj\r\n<<\r\n/Filter 3 0 R\r\n/Length 4 0 R\r\n/Length1 1036584\r\n>>\r\nstream\r\nx��\a�%E�?~��\034ox�M�1�0y`�\031\026�Q\034\020q\b\002�C\020D\021\0312\b\n��Q$\030pU�E@\004\004D@1`Bwa\021AP1�\021E�\twu\025#0���������7o\006v�>��o�;U����+�:�N�����D�˻w]��n�|{���\030�Qd�\033w���k���\035R,?F�{�n�>���/K�\017_�����\036��\'�z�礵�7E����k�_s��cCi}�\032�:{����~�\027\016�Od��t.~��e+F�|�[\005\017��K�}�^�?�����^��\035\016�u�\027�����(r�����#N<���_��\006iv�\027Y�#^}�\026\037�����\vv\024\t_~��G����-��3\016\025�>~�᧜,3�i(�\004��>���\034uY��K���\\�m\017=f݉����+~"r�/���9����=�\003�.Ҹ��?\006\027���:\f稯�=��SO;��'...) /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php:793
    0.0585    9191832  15. tcpdi_parser->getRawObject($offset = 'Type', $data = '\r\n%Devtype SAPWIN   Font ZARIAL1  normal Lang ES\r\n/Type /Font\r\n/Subtype /TrueType\r\n/BaseFont /Arial\r\n/Name /F001\r\n/Encoding 6 0 R\r\n/FirstChar 32\r\n/LastChar 255\r\n%Charwidth values from SAPWIN ZARIAL1 120 normal\r\n/Widths\r\n[ 275 275 354 554 554 888 667 192 333 333 388 583 275 333 275 275 554 554 554 554 554 554 554 554 554 554 275 275 583 583 583 554 1017 667 667 721 721 667 608 775 721 275 500 667 554 833 721 775 667 775 721 667 608 721 667 942 667 667 608 275 275 275 471\r\n 554 333 554 554 500 554 554 275 554'...) /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php:911

Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utlr' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utls' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utlt' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utlu' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utlv' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utlw' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utlx' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utly' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utlz' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utma' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utmb' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utmc' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utmd' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utme' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utmf' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utmg' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utmh' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utmi' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utmj' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utmk' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utml' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utmm' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utmn' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utmo' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utmp' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utmq' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utmr' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utms' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]
Warning: Illegal string offset 'Utmt' in /share/ZFS2_DATA/Web/dolibarr/htdocs/includes/tcpdi/tcpdi_parser.php on line 706
[...]

and it just keeps printing the same warnings forever.
